# EF Core 2.1 Slow Performance With Two Include() Statements on a simple query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am running a .NET Core 2.1 Web API, hosted in Azure. My database is also hosted in Azure.

Using EF Core 2.1, I am attempting to pull some data out of that database. I have set up a ConsoleLoggerProvider in order to monitor the SQL queries that EF Core is generating and monitor the execution time of those queries.

I have found a few similar questions posted on StackOverflow, but those questions typically involve queries with several .Include() statements, GroupBy() statements, lots of where filters, using an older version of Entity Framework, not using a .Take() statement, etc. This problem involves a very simple query with only two Include() statements and only selecting a TOP 100.

Here is what my database schema looks like:

--

**Ticket**

ID int (primary key)

TicketNumber int (not null)

MemberID int (not null)(foreign key)

AreaID int (not null)(foreign key)

SettledDateTime datetime

IsDeleted bit (not null)

**Area**

ID int (primary key)

Name nvarchar

**Member**

ID int (primary key)

FirstName nvarchar

LastName nvarchar

--

The following LINQ statement takes 54ms to run in the database (according to the ConsoleLoggerProvider output):

```
var results = unitOfWork.Tickets
                .Where(x => x.SettledDateTime != null && !x.IsDeleted)
                .Include(x => x.Member)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
                .Take(100)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.ID,
                    x.TicketNumber,
                    x.Member.FirstName,
                    x.Member.LastName,
                }
                .ToList();
```

A similar LINQ statement, selecting an Area name instead of a Member's first and last name, takes 55ms to run in the database (according to the ConsoleLoggerProvider output):

```
var results = unitOfWork.Tickets
                .Where(x => x.SettledDateTime != null && !x.IsDeleted)
                .Include(x => x.Area)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
                .Take(100)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.ID,
                    x.TicketNumber,
                    x.Area.Name,
                }
                .ToList();
```

However, if I select both the member's first/last name and the area name, the execution time in the database jumps to 2,872ms:

```
var results = unitOfWork.Tickets
                .Where(x => x.SettledDateTime != null && !x.IsDeleted)
                .Include(x => x.Member)
                .Include(x => x.Area)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
                .Take(100)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.ID,
                    x.TicketNumber,
                    x.Member.FirstName,
                    x.Member.LastName,
                    x.Area.Name,
                }
                .ToList();
```

Here is the raw SQL that my ConsoleLoggerProvider is telling me is running in the database for all three cases

```
  Executed DbCommand (54ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [x].[ID], [x].[TicketNumber], [x.Member].[FirstName], [x.Member].[LastName]
  FROM [Ticket] AS [x]
  INNER JOIN [Member] AS [x.Member] ON [x].[MemberID] = [x.Member].[ID]
  WHERE [x].[SettledDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND ([x].[IsDeleted] = 0)
  ORDER BY [x].[ID] DESC

  Executed DbCommand (55ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [x].[ID], [x].[TicketNumber], [x.Area].[Name]
  FROM [Ticket] AS [x]
  INNER JOIN [Area] AS [x.Area] ON [x].[AreaID] = [x.Area].[ID]
  WHERE [x].[SettledDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND ([x].[IsDeleted] = 0)
  ORDER BY [x].[ID] DESC


  Executed DbCommand (2,872ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [x].[ID], [x].[TicketNumber], [x].[MemberID], [x.Member].[FirstName], [x.Member].[LastName], [x.Area].[Name]
  FROM [Ticket] AS [x]
  INNER JOIN [Area] AS [x.Area] ON [x].[AreaID] = [x.Area].[ID]
  INNER JOIN [Member] AS [x.Member] ON [x].[MemberID] = [x.Member].[ID]
  WHERE [x].[SettledDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND ([x].[IsDeleted] = 0)
  ORDER BY [x].[ID] DESC
```

The Ticket table in this example has 75,803 records, the Member table 147,157 records, and the Area table 691 records.

I cannot figure out why joining in both tables causes the query execution time to jump so drastically. If I run that last query directly in the database, it takes less than a second to execute and show results.

**UPDATE:** If I remove the .OrderByDescending, performance improves drastically (down to **78ms**). Here is an updated LINQ statement:

```
var results = unitOfWork.Tickets
                .Where(x => x.SettledDateTime != null && !x.IsDeleted)
                .Take(100)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.ID,
                    x.TicketNumber,
                    x.Member.FirstName,
                    x.Member.LastName,
                    x.Area.Name,
                }
                .ToList();
```

And here's the ConsoleLoggerProvider output:

```
  Executed DbCommand (78ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [x].[ID], [x].[TicketNumber], [x.Member].[FirstName], [x.Member].[LastName], [x.Area].[Name]
  FROM [Ticket] AS [x]
  INNER JOIN [Area] AS [x.Area] ON [x].[AreaID] = [x.Area].[ID]
  INNER JOIN [Member] AS [x.Member] ON [x].[MemberID] = [x.Member].[ID]
  WHERE [x].[SettledDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND ([x].[IsDeleted] = 0)
```

Comment: That example is not doing a SELECT TOP (i.e. a .Take()), and with logging turned on, that person's example is executing 20-30 SELECT statements. My ConsoleLoggerProvider is showing that only one SELECT statement is being executed in each case, and I'm doing a .Take(100).

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't read queries with enough attention - this one isn't a duplicate, just not because of Take or whatever, but because you are doing a projection, so Includes have nothing to do with it - they are actually even **unnecessary**.

Comment: So the issue is probably with indexes on your tables - do you have indexes on your foreign key columns?

Comment: `I run that last query directly in the database, it takes less than a second to execute and show results` can probably be explained by some peculiarities of (execution plan and results) caching.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I do not have indexes on the AreaID or MemberID columns on the Ticket table. When I looked at the execution plan in SQL Server Management Studio it told me it was doing Clustered Index Scan/Clustered Index Seek since the ID columns on the Member and Area tables are primary keys/clustered indexes.

The execution plan didn't recommend any indexes and Azure doesn't have any performance recommendations for the table (it does have some for other, unrelated tables that I'll eventually apply).

Comment: I could see it being an index issue, I'm just surprised that running the query directly in the database runs so match faster, even on the first try. If I run my .NET Core application in Debug mode and keep executing the LINQ statement over and over the performance is always the same (2.5 to 3 seconds). I'm guessing the connection via Entity Framework is just never caching the execution plan?

Comment: Hm, those indexes are not really needed for such queries, though `x.SettledDateTime != null && !x.IsDeleted` may be a good candidate. Asking to check/add indexes is a bit of a learned knee-jerk reaction for all SQL performance issues, so... In such a case I am inclined to think that it is some weird execution plan issue due to parameters in queries. Not sure how to properly check it though. Perhaps as a temporary stop-gap issue you may use Stored Procedure that does the same thing.

Comment: Turn on Query Store, and make sure you're getting the same query plan when running from EF.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017  (also you can omit the `.Includes` they have no effect when you project a a result type).

Comment: I checked the Query Store settings for my Azure SQL Database and it was already set to Read Write as you suggested: https://imgur.com/MTYiZVK

I did remove the .Includes as you suggested. I tested removing the .Where and that did not improve performance. Curiously, if I remove the .OrderByDescending, the query speeds up significantly.

Comment: Curiously? Ordering is the most performance affecting operation of "paging" queries. What if you do `OrderBy` (instead of `OrderByDescending`)? Anyway, the generated SQL query by EF Core is just fine, also since your are using projection, `Includes` are ignored and the quey is no tracking, so the problem seem to be out of EF Core, but in database - bad SQL execution plan (full table scan or something). What happens if you remove the `Where` clause just for the sake of test? Or replace `TOP(@__p_0)` parameter with constant, which I guess is what you are doing when executing it "directly" to db?